# Database object backup using script(PS/SQLCMD)

Tags: sql-server, database, azure-devops

I have a Azure DevOps release pipeline for, Sql server deployment. This task deploys all .sql scripts present in 'Drop' folder.

But before performing deployment we want to take backup, DB management and DB backup is handled by different team so my responsibility is to simple take backup of SPs and SSIS packages as these deployments are more frequent. I'm planning to add a task line Cmd or Powershell task which will perform the backup for only SPs or SSIS packages.

I know how to take DB Object backup manually using in SSMS by Tasks > Generate Scripts >  Select DB > Select Store Procedures.

and i found a script to perform this backup task but it will take whole Database backup.

```sql
USE [master]
GO
 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
 
-- =============================================
-- Backup Database using a stored procedure
-- =============================================
 
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Backup_Database] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
 
@DBName nvarchar(255), 
@Location nvarchar(255)   
 
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
 
SET NOCOUNT ON;
 
Declare @DBFileName nvarchar(255)
 
Set @DBFileName = datename(DD,getdate())+'_'+datename(M,getdate())+'_'+
datename(YYYY,getdate())+'_'+replace(replace(@DBName,':','_'),'\','_')+'.bak'
 
Select @DBFileName
 
EXEC ('BACKUP DATABASE ['+ @DBName +'] TO  DISK = N'''+ @Location + 
        @DBFileName +''' WITH COPY_ONLY,  NAME = N'''+ @DBName +'-Full Database Backup''')
END
```

[image]

Comment: Careful, the above is wide open to injection attacks. `'['+ @DBName +']'` is **not** safe from injection. (Imagine if someone passed the value `master]; CREATE DATABASE NewDB;--`, what do you think would happen?) `@Location` also suffers the same problem. Use `QUOTENAME` and `REPLACE` to *safely* inject your strings. *`@DBName` should also be a `sysname`; object names can't be longer than 128 characters.*

Comment: Hi akshay, any update on this? Did you get a chance to implement the solution that Larnu suggested? Were you able to resolve?